# How to submit a form using Ctrl+S with Codemirror key bindings

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I have a basic form with Codemirror implemented. I want to bind the keys Ctrl + S to submit the form. I found the Ctrl + S (extrakeys) function for Codemirror, but  I have no idea what to put in there.

```
<form action="action.htm" method="post" id="myform">
  <textarea name="editor" id="editor" class="codemirror-area"></textarea>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>   
</form>

<script>
 var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
    lineNumbers: true,
    autoCloseTags: true,
    setSize: (200,200),
    indentWithTabs: true,
    theme: "default",   
    lineWrapping: true,         
    extraKeys: {
      "F11": function(cm) {
      cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
      },
      "Esc": function(cm) {
      if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
      },
      "Ctrl-S": function(instance) { 
      saveText(instance.getValue()); },
      }      
     }
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. If you want with Codemirror.

> ```
>  var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("editor"), {
>    lineNumbers: true,
>    autoCloseTags: true,
>    setSize: (200,200),
>    indentWithTabs: true,
>    theme: "default",   
>    lineWrapping: true,         
>    extraKeys: {
>      "F11": function(cm) {
>        cm.setOption("fullScreen", !cm.getOption("fullScreen"));
>      },
>      "Esc": function(cm) {
>       if (cm.getOption("fullScreen")) cm.setOption("fullScreen", false);
>     },
>     "Ctrl-S": function(instance) { 
>       $("#myform").submit();
>     },
>   }      
> });
> ```

Or alternative method:

1. First add jquery library.
2. After add this code:

> ```
> jQuery(document).keydown(function(event) {
>             if((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.which == 83) {
>                 // Save Function
>                 $("#myform").submit();
>                 event.preventDefault();
>                 return false;
>             }
>         }
>     );
> ```

This is better :)

Comment: Thank you. Just a question, why do you say the jquery option is better?

Comment: if codemirror is used and there is a function to add shortcuts, it should be used. no additional library needed. If the function did not work, I would use jquery. So I said better, because there is always a solution. for smile :)

Comment: i recommend use ajax. because every time press ctrl+s page is reload. but with ajax page not reload and show alert "saved" message.